# Traefik: Restore cloudflare real ip securely?

Tags: traefik

Cloudflare proxy includes a header named CF-Connecting-IP with the user's real ip. I would like to have traefik read this header and create a X-Real-Ip header with it's contents, but only if the source ip is a trusted/whitelisted one.

In the past I've used nginx and was able to do this using the [http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

Is there a way to achieve something like this with traefik?

Comment: Good question. I recently reinstalled my vps with LAMP stack and changed to a traefik with multiple docker projects setup. In Apache i used mod_cloudflare for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found those two plugins for traefik, that are capable of modifying the header:

https://github.com/XciD/traefik-plugin-rewrite-headers
or if you are already using pilot:
https://pilot.traefik.io/plugins/605afbe6a5f67ab9a1b0e540/rewrite-header

But based on the Cloudflare Documentation the CF-Connecting-IP header shares the real ip with the X-Forwarded-For header. The builtin traefik middleware https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/ipwhitelist/ uses the x-forwarded-for header for allowing/denying access.